# Focused element is hidden behind fixed menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a site with a menu at the bottom that i set to position fixed. It remains when scrolling.

When using keyboard tab to navigate the site the focused element is automatically scrolled to if it isn't already in the viewport. The problem here is that when a focused element is scolled to it doesn't show because it is behind the fixed menu that have at the bottom.

Any idéa of how I can solve this so that the window is scrolled a litte more to that the focused element shows.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your scrolling code:

```
// lets say element is the DOM element you want to scroll into view
function scrollNow(element) {
   // create a dummy element X pixels above 'element' 
   // where X is the height of your bottom menu
   // if X is not known in advance, calculate it using $('#menu').outerHeight()
   var dummy = $('<div></div>').css({
      position: 'absolute', top: $(element).offset().top - X 
   }).appendTo('body');
   dummy[0].scrollIntoView();
   dummy.remove(); // remove the dummy element
}
```

Comment: cool, looks promising. now, how do I catch the events when i should run this code?this should fire only when an element has received focus by tabbing to it.

Comment: For that, you should be calling this on `onblur`, i.e. `$('.x').blur(function() { scrollNow(this); });` - replace .x as needed

Comment: but won't that event contain the wrong element? the blured (previously focused) element instead of the newly focused. somehow i should also make a check if it gained through tabbing and not by click for example.

Comment: Oops! I meant the `.focus(..)` event, not the `.blur(..)` event. My mistake. Apologies. `$('.x').focus(function() { scrollNow(this); });` is the way to go.

Comment: good. but what about the tabkey check that i want to do? i don't want to run this on every focus event only when focus is gained by tabbing. focus by click should not run scrollNow()

Comment: how an element gained focus is difficult to find if not impossible. also, i believe scrollIntoView() won't do anything if the thing is already visible.

Comment: scrollIntoView seem to always scroll the element as high up as possible (at least in FF). so it scrolls also on click now which is not intended.